# Computation of the Moore Complex

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-stuff

Given a simplicial abelian group G, one can compute its simplicial homotopy groups as the homology groups of its associated Moore complex. Can someone please show me the explicit computation of the Moore complex of a simplicial abelian group? I could only find one example of this (nLab entry on the Moore complex).